# What is considered a bomb tower's "footprint"?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

In Bloons Monkey City, the 3rd rank (upgraded using Monkey Knowledge Packs) in for the bomb tower says that the "footprint is reduced 5%". What does that mean, and how does it affect my game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [footprint](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Footprint) is how much space a tower takes up.  So reducing the footprint means that you can fit more bomb towers in the same space.  This can be helpful on maps that have limited land (e.g. water tiles) or if you are trying to fit a bunch of towers under the same Monkey Village.

Comment: Nice link, helped a lot!